# Django Error: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing

Tags: django

I'm trying to make records for my database of a web-based course planning application in an institution. My concern is that of not being able to make recordings in the intermediary table resulting from the relation M2M in views.py but it works in shell

ValueError at /config/departement

The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/config/departement
Django Version:     2.1.7
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:

The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

Exception Location:     C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py in process_rhs, line 257
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe
Python Version:     3.7.0
Python Path:

Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

```
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner

                response = get_response(request)

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response

                    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response

                    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

     ...
▶ Local vars
E:\PLACORESA\configuration\views.py in departemnent

                cursus = get_object_or_404(Cursus, libelle_cursus=cursus )

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py in get_object_or_404

            return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in get

            num = len(clone)

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in __len__

            self._fetch_all()

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in _fetch_all

                self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in __iter__

            results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py in execute_sql

                sql, params = self.as_sql()

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py in as_sql

                    where, w_params = self.compile(self.where) if self.where is not None else ("", [])

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py in compile

                sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\where.py in as_sql

                    sql, params = compiler.compile(child)

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py in compile

                sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py in as_sql

            rhs_sql, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)

     ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py in process_rhs

                        'The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to '

     ...
▶ Local vars
```

models.py

```
class Departement(models.Model):
    code_departement=models.CharField("code du département", max_length=100, unique=True)
    libelle_departement=models.CharField("Libellé du département", max_length=100)
    faculte=models.ForeignKey("Faculte", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cursus=models.ManyToManyField("Cursus", through="AvoirCursus")   



class Cursus(models.Model):
    code_cursus=models.CharField("Code du cursus", max_length=10, unique=True)
    libelle_cursus=models.CharField("Libellé du cursus", max_length=100) 

class AvoirCursus(models.Model):
    cursus=models.ForeignKey("Cursus", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    departement=models.ForeignKey("Departement", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        f = forms.Departement_Form(request.POST)
        if f.is_valid():
            dept = f.save(commit=False)
            code_departement = f.cleaned_data['code_departement'].upper()
            dept.code_departement = code_departement
            cursus = f.cleaned_data['cursus']
            dept.save()
            cursus = get_object_or_404(Cursus, libelle_cursus=cursus )
            print(cursus)
            AvoirCursus.objects.create(departement=dept, cursus=cursus)

            return redirect('configuration:lister_departement')
```

Comment: Post whole error message with traceback please.

Answer (score 0):

This can't work.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
            (...)
            dept=models.Departement.objects.get(code_departement=code_departement)
            cursus=models.Cursus.objects.get(code_cursus=cursus)
            avoircursus=models.AvoirCursus.objects.create(cursus=cursus, departemnent=dept)
```

I removed `models`

```
if request.method == 'POST':
     (...)
     dept = Departement.objects.get(code_departement=code_departement)
     cursus = Cursus.objects.get(code_cursus=cursus)
```

To create a `AvoirCursus` instance which in a throught model.

```
AvoirCursus.objects.create((cursus=cursus, departemnent=dept)
```

I tested it and it works, at least in my console.

```
# your models
class Faculte(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Libellé du département", max_length=100

class Departement(models.Model):
    code_departement = models.CharField("code du département", max_length=100, unique=True)
    libelle_departement = models.CharField("Libellé du département", max_length=100)
    faculte = models.ForeignKey("Faculte", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cursus = models.ManyToManyField("Cursus", through="AvoirCursus")

class Cursus(models.Model):
    code_cursus = models.CharField("Code du cursus", max_length=10, unique=True)
    libelle_cursus = models.CharField("Libellé du cursus", max_length=100)

class AvoirCursus(models.Model):
    cursus = models.ForeignKey("Cursus", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    departement = models.ForeignKey("Departement", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here is what I did to check it:

```
f = Faculte.objects.create(name='Sorbonne')
c = Cursus.objects.create(code_cursus='404')
d = Departement.objects.create(code_departement='code', libelle_departement='libelle', faculte=f)
ac = AvoirCursus.objects.create(cursus=c, departement=d)
```

This works perfectly. So you must have something wrong in your view. Or maybe rebuild your db if you made changes that are not reflected.

Comment: Please, I have the same exception raised at the line: cursus = Cursus.objects.get (code_cursus = cursus). 
I have removed models and changed the call of my models that was from. import models from .models import *

Comment: yes i tried **dept.cursus.add (cursus)** ; I get an AttibuteError exception: **Can not use add () on ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediate model. Use configuration.AvoirCursus's Manager instead.**

Comment: the right way to add it via a through relation is AvoirCursus.objects.create((cursus=cursus, departemnent=dept) considering that you have 2 **created** instances of ```Cursus``` and ```Department```.

Comment: Sorry but it is not walking

Comment: I've edited my post. I just tested this code and it works. So can you be more precise ? Can you paste a new message with your view?

Comment: This is extract of my views.py code_departement=f.cleaned_data['code_departement'].upper()
   dept.code_departement=code_departement
   cursus=f.cleaned_data['cursus']
   dept.save()
   cursus=get_object_or_404(Cursus, libelle_cursus=cursus )
   AvoirCursus.objects.create( cursus=cursus, departement=dept).                  When I execute it  in shell it works but not in views.py

Comment: can you post code in new post next time. It's quite hard to read like this. Also, you should respect PEP8 for clarity sake !

Comment: what's the traceback error? Check if you got valid instances with pdb. do you really get cursus? dept? If yes, it should work. Post your complet view please.

Comment: Sir @Emilio conte I've put traceback I need your help please

Comment: try to remove this useless line **dept=models.Departement.objects.get(code_departement=code_departement)** You already have ```dept```. There's no reason to reload it from db. From the error you got, I bet ```dept``` is not the expected item. It might be a queryset. you should provide the real view, you're using. I don't think it's what you put here AFAICS.

Comment: Sir @Emilio Conte  I have update my views.py . Know you have the real views!!

Comment: Did you use ```pdb``` to debug your view? ```import ipdb; pdb.set_trace()```  in your view and test your values. Is ```type(dept)``` a Departement instance? Is ```type(cursus)``` a real Cursus instance? The error might come from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I've succeeded to resolve my problème. The forms used in views is the generic form from models.py. when I've print(cursus ) the result was a queryset containing selected items.To write in the intermediate database, I made the course of "cursus" to have the different objects.

**the views.py is:**

```
if f.is_valid():
            dept = f.save(commit=False)
            code_departement = f.cleaned_data['code_departement']
            dept.code_departement = code_departement
            print(code_departement)
            cursus = f.cleaned_data['cursus']
            dept.save()
            for i in cursus:
                AvoirCursus.objects.create(departement=dept, cursus=i)
```